# How to set image dynamically in Adaptive card

Tags: adaptive-cards

I am trying below snippet to set image as per if else condition but its now working as expected it always empty
Image is one of my column name which am using in adaptive card

```
"items": [       
    {
        "type": "Image",
        "url": "${if({Image} == Test, 'https://test.sharepoint.com/mysite/mylib/Test.png', if({Image} == Test1, 'https://test.sharepoint.com/mysite/mylib/Test1.png')}",
        "size": "Medium",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
        "altText": "Result logo"                                            
    }                                        
]
```

Comment: Where are you using this code? In SPFx ACE or Power Automate or anywhere else?

Comment: i am using search layout designer to design adaptive card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using when condition so below is the syntax

```
{
"type": "Image",
"url": " https://test.sharepoint.com/mysite/mylib/Test.png",
"size": "Small",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"altText": "Result logo",
"$when": "${Image== 'Test'}"
},
{
"type": "Image",
"url": " https://test.sharepoint.com/mysite/mylib/Test1.png",
"size": "Small",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"altText": "Result logo",
"$when": "${Image== 'Test1'}"
},
{
"type": "Image",
"url": " https://test.sharepoint.com/mysite/mylib/Test2.png",
"size": "Small",
"horizontalAlignment": "Center",
"altText": "Result logo",
 "$when": "${Image== 'Test2'}"
 }
```